# android apk file size gets doubled on market

Tags: android

I have recently uploaded an application on the android market, and i have noticed that the application size is appearing 2X on the market.

Could someone please help in figuring out the reason and solution to bring it back to original size .

will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have ***copy protection*** enabled in your application configuration/manifest file.

Refer to the following link - http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/372e6aff4601beaa#

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the size reported on http://market.android.com ? or the app size on the phone after downloading from the market?

After installing the app, it will occupy more space on the phone because it is installed in the uncompressed form.